# Change woocommerce product variation description to term description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We would like to have the variable product description fixed instead of changing it for each product. By default Woocommerce shows the variable product description in the frontend:
[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmMlp.jpg) [Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E6BA.jpg)

What I would like is that term description (attribute value description) is shown here. [Attribute value description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZz5N.jpg)

I checked the woocommerce file templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php and copied it to my template folder so we can override this. In this file there is mention of:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
```

So what I would like is that the description from the term is displayed here instead of the variation description.