# WooCommerce - How can I switch the custom product variation description that's displayed on select with the global product variation desc

Tags: woocommerce

All my product attribute variation terms are global (due to a plugin requirement) and that's where all the descriptions are.  I am using Astra theme and this displays the attribute description when one is selected, but since it displays only custom ones from the product settings, mine are not showing.

I would like to switch out the value displayed.  Exactly the same as this question which was unfortunately never answered:  [Change woocommerce product variation description to term description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732487/change-woocommerce-product-variation-description-to-term-description)   (he has screenshots)

I know how to get the value that I want `get_term_field( 'description', $term->term_id );` but no idea where to switch it out.